# ViewModel using CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, mvvm

I've an entity with 30 attributes.
But my view display list of objects and it only needs 2 attributes of an entity.
When I fetch list of entities, each object is huge with 30 attributes where as I only need 2 attributes for displaying.
Is there a way to fetch an entity with only 2 attributes? (Something like creating view-model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can do with the `propertiesToFetch` property in `NSFetchRequest`.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ENTITY_NAME", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["property1","property2"]
fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```

fetchRequest's `resultType` must be set to `NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType`.

And you will get array of dictionary objects not NSManagedObject objects.

Comment: Is it possible to set the keys for which property will be set? Something like a custom model class

Comment: Can i get objectID, is objectID is considered as it's property?